# How to evaluate the complex integral involving exponential functions?

Tags: integration, complex-integration

I am trying to solve the following definite integral.

$$\int_{-\infty}^0  e^{\omega (i(x - z) + |a - y|)} d \omega + \int_{0}^\infty e^{\omega (i(x - z) - |a - y|)} d\omega$$

where $i$ is the imaginary number, $a, x, y, z$ are constants.

I get that it's equal to

$$ \frac{2|a - y|}{(a - y)^2 + (x - z)^2}.$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Seems correct..

Comment: @an4s What is your method of deriving the integral?

Comment: Substitute $u = w(i(x - z) + \vert a - y\vert), v = w(i(x - z) - \vert a - y\vert)$.